# Using ubuntu font on my web app

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

I am planning to use Ubuntu font for my Django web app. I have downloaded the font here : http://font.ubuntu.com/ . So far I managed to enable the font by putting link to Google API; by pasting this line of code in my html file `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:regular,bold&subset=Latin">`

However, the server of my web app will not connected to the internet, as it shall be internal use only. Will the above method still work this way? If not, how can I embed the downloaded font in my web application?

Comment: Nullable makes a good point. Are the clients connected to the interent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which fonts from the typeface do you actually need?

It is as simple as:
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:regular,bold,italic
returns:

```
@media screen {
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Ubuntu Italic'), local('Ubuntu-Italic'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/ubuntu/v4/kbP_6ONYVgE-bLa9ZRbvvvesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff') format('woff');
}
}
@media screen {
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Ubuntu'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/ubuntu/v4/_xyN3apAT_yRRDeqB3sPRg.woff') format('woff');
}
}
@media screen {
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  src: local('Ubuntu Bold'), local('Ubuntu-Bold'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/ubuntu/v4/0ihfXUL2emPh0ROJezvraD8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff') format('woff');
}
}
```

Download each of the WOFF files you wish to use, as seen by the 'src' property, and place these in your static directory, and change the 'src' url in the CSS to match your own url.

EG, for the normal font, you should download: http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/ubuntu/v4/_xyN3apAT_yRRDeqB3sPRg.woff 
place it in /static/ubuntu_normal.woff

and create the following CSS:

```
@media screen {
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Ubuntu'), url('/static/ubuntu_normal.woff') format('woff');
}
}
```

You will need to add each of the font-styles or font-faces that you wish to use, bold, italic, etc.

Answer (score 1):

CSS runs client-sided. As long as the clients are internet-connected it will work.